# Create Web Forms N2 CMS App Based on N2 Templates

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, n2, n2cms

I have gone through the N2 CMS documentation at length and can see no obvious set of steps to accomplish this.

The task is to create a new Web Forms CMS app based on N2. Basically to take the Stripes theme and customize it.

I originally downloaded the full source code and got it working on my development machine with SQL Server. After this I made various attempts at copying the files necessary to run the application into the new Web Forms folder in wwwroot. I got a lot of the same runtime errors that I see others getting, relating to missing DLLs,  browser control adapters, and the like.

My current approach, per the "howto_install.txt", is to use the Publish function to move the required files to my wwwroot folder. This is really not desirable if I want to work on CMS sites for three different clients - think about it. Either way, when I bring up the new site in the wwwroot folder now, **the home page link on the home page, all image links, and all admin links are now broken** (this happened after moving site to IIS7). The install document mentions copying the "N2 management files" to the new folder - can anyone explain what is meant by this?

Can anyone assist in outlining the basic steps in getting a new Web Forms N2 site working with full functionality in the wwwroot folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this to work by using the Web Platform Installer to install the Web Deployment Tool on my machine. Then I downloaded the Web Form Templates version of N2 CMS from CodePlex and used the Import Package link in IIS7 to pull in the downloaded zip file.

I outlined the steps here - thanks to Cristian Libardo for his help with this:

http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2010/07/03/N2CMS.aspx